# RabbitMQ - WebSocket Connection Overflow Issue

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs, rabbitmq-cluster

We implemented Web Sockete in our Spring MVC application using STOMP and RabbitMQ cluster. We are facing an issue that virtual host in RabbitMQ is getting deleted (noticed 3 times in 2 days) and then we had to manually add it back.

Errors in RabbitMQ log file:

```
[error] <0.9701.771> Error on AMQP connection <0.9701.771> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:51566 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:5672 - connectionFactory#70ea3f70:7, vhost: '/', user: 'xxxxx', state: running), channel 0:
operation none caused a connection exception connection_forced: "Closed due to web socket connection overflow"
[info] <0.26035.771> Closing connection <0.9701.771> because "Closed due to web socket connection overflow"
[info] <0.9701.771> closing AMQP connection <0.9701.771> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:51566 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:5672 - connectionFactory#70ea3f70:7, vhost: '/', user: 'xxxxx')
[error] <0.17457.771> Error on AMQP connection <0.17457.771> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:50398 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:5672 - connectionFactory#452a8dc0:2, vhost: '/', user: 'xxxxx', state: running), channel 0:
operation none caused a connection exception connection_forced: "Closed due to web socket connection overflow"
[info] <0.24839.771> Closing connection <0.17457.771> because "Closed due to web socket connection overflow"
[info] <0.17457.771> closing AMQP connection <0.17457.771> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:50398 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:5672 - connectionFactory#452a8dc0:2, vhost: '/', user: 'xxxxx')
[info] <0.23883.771> accepting STOMP connection <0.23883.771> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:53902 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:61613)
[warning] <0.24395.771> STOMP detected missed client heartbeat(s) on connection xx.xxx.xx.xx:54978 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:61613, closing it
[info] <0.26250.771> accepting STOMP connection <0.26250.771> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:55256 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:61613)
[info] <0.21662.771> Deleting vhost '/'
[info] <0.22762.771> closing STOMP connection <0.22762.771> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:51136 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:61613)
[info] <0.24314.771> closing STOMP connection <0.24314.771> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:53670 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:61613)
[info] <0.9594.767> closing STOMP connection <0.9594.767> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:53128 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:61613)
[info] <0.23883.771> closing STOMP connection <0.23883.771> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:53902 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:61613)
[info] <0.26250.771> closing STOMP connection <0.26250.771> (xx.xxx.xx.xx:55256 -> xx.xxx.xx.xx:61613)
```